# Artifactory failed to initialize due to derby file log size

Tags: artifactory, derby

i'm stuck with an artifactory problem, my artifactory webpage return a `500 status failed to initialize`.

First I try to restart the service `systemclt restart artifactory.service`. The service start with any error output during the operation. Here the output of a `systemctl status artifactory` after the restart, I try to stop and start too but same result:

```
➜  log systemctl status artifactory.service -l
● artifactory.service - LSB: Start Artifactory on Tomcat
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/artifactory)
   Active: active (running) since mer. 2020-07-22 15:42:06 CEST; 1h 50min ago
  Process: 4751 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/artifactory stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4849 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/artifactory start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4915 (java)
   CGroup: /system.slice/artifactory.service
           ‣ 4915 /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/artifactory/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -server -Xms512m -Xmx2g -Xss256k -XX:+UseG1GC -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Dartdist=zip -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true -Dartifactory.home=/home/artifactory -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/artifactory/tomcat/endorsed -classpath /home/artifactory/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/artifactory/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/home/artifactory/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/home/artifactory/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/artifactory/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

juil. 22 15:42:04 ns337904.ip-**-***-***.** artifactory[4849]: Using ARTIFACTORY_PID: /home/artifactory/run/artifactory.pid
juil. 22 15:42:04 ns337904.ip-**-***-***.** artifactory[4849]: Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/artifactory/tomcat
juil. 22 15:42:04 ns337904.ip-**-***-***.** artifactory[4849]: Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/artifactory/tomcat
juil. 22 15:42:04 ns337904.ip-**-***-***.** artifactory[4849]: Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/artifactory/tomcat/temp
juil. 22 15:42:04 ns337904.ip-**-***-***.** artifactory[4849]: Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
juil. 22 15:42:04 ns337904.ip-**-***-***.** artifactory[4849]: Using CLASSPATH:       /home/artifactory/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/artifactory/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
juil. 22 15:42:04 ns337904.ip-**-***-***.** artifactory[4849]: Using CATALINA_PID:    /home/artifactory/run/artifactory.pid
juil. 22 15:42:04 ns337904.ip-**-***-***.** artifactory[4849]: Tomcat started.
juil. 22 15:42:06 ns337904.ip-**-***-***.** artifactory[4849]: Artifactory Tomcat started in normal mode
juil. 22 15:42:06 ns337904.ip-**-***-***.** systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Artifactory on Tomcat.
```

But problem isn't fixed. The first error before the restart in the artifactory.log : https://pastebin.com/XEfFmN19

After the restart : https://pastebin.com/EJLAJT91

When I go to the derby.log file same error logged with no more informations. The concerned file(i think) by the error :

```
➜  cd /home/artifactory/data/derby/log
➜  log ll
total 257M
-rw-r--r-- 1 artifactory artifactory 256M juil. 17 01:05 log3955.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        artifactory    0 juil. 22 15:42 log3956.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 artifactory artifactory   48 juil. 22 15:42 log.ctrl
-rw-r--r-- 1 artifactory artifactory   48 juil. 22 15:42 logmirror.ctrl
-rw-r--r-- 1 artifactory artifactory  532 juil. 10  2016 README_DO_NOT_TOUCH_FILES.txt
```

So apparently it's a size log file problem. But I don't know how to solve that.
I search in the artifactory conf and see nothing to upgrade the max allow size.
I see nothing in the artifacory docs about that. Anyway I don't know if it's the best way to handle the problem.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you consider using an outside db instead of using derby
this [link](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-2827) suggests some workarounds on reclaiming space or changing the default storage